# JOptionPane with two labels

Tags: java, jlabel, joptionpane

I would like to create in Java a JOptionPane which should contain two different labels, Is it possible? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JOptionPane do not consist of labels. It's a built in component for showing a standard pop up box with various buttons. You might wish to implement your own JFrame, that looks identical to a normal JOptionPane, with however way/many text included.

Answer (score 4):

Your message parameter can be an array of JComponent objects which will be drawn in sequence. An example would be:

```
JLabel[] arr = {new JLabel("Paragraph 1"), new JLabel("Paragraph 2")};
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a `\n` in the string you want to print, so for instance "Hello\nWorld" would look like

```
Hello
World
```

which is similar to having to labels.

There are other escape characters, you can take a look at them [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)